# Add UIView that hovers over UINavigationController's UINavigationBar, but pushes with the view that adds it?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

So, adding a view that appears over the `UINavigationBar` in a `UINavigationController` is easy enough:

`self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(testView);`

However, getting that `UIView` to **push/transition alongside `UIViewController` changes** in that navigation flow is more tricky. Aside from simply fading the view `alpha` from `1` to `0` or vice versa on appear/disappear, is there an elegant solution/hack for getting the horizontal position of the view to stay centered, for example?

[image: screenshot of a <code>UIView</code> hovering over a <code>UINavigationBar</code> in a <code>UINavigationController</code>]

---

**EDIT:** The reason why setting `titleView` on the `UIViewController`'s `navigationItem` won't work is because when another view is popping it clips the titleView... *(compare this image to the one above)*

[image: screenshot of <code>titleView</code> clipping during pop]

Comment: why not use a  `titleView `

Comment: It's a bit glitchy if the `UIView` exceeds the bounds of the `UINavigationBar`. The other parts of it are clipped until the animation finishes!

Comment: To clarify, `titleView` almost works perfectly. The issue here is that when animating **back** from a `UIViewController` that is popping... it clips the top and bottom of the `titleView` to be inside of the bounds of `UINavigationBar`. That's not OK, because as you can see from the image above, it overlaps onto the view below on purpose.

Comment: I added a screenshot above to demonstrate that.